# Mentions in a rich embed are appearing as their string

Tags: discord.js

I'm having a problem where my bot does not mention correctly in rich embeds. It appears to be unable to tag a user at all.

A mention ends up looking like...

> `<@601756839956447232>`

It *should* ping the user and look like...

> [image: @StackOverflow]

---

- I've tried doing `author.toString()` in my message.
- I've tried using `<@${author.id}>`.
- I've tried using `@${author.tag}`.
- I've tried using `${author}`.

All of these attempts produce the same result.

---

This is the code I'm using...

```js
var serv = message.guild
var author = message.author

var myInfo = new discord.RichEmbed()
    .setAuthor(`${serv.name}'s roles`,`${message.guild.iconURL}`)
    .addField(`Roles`, serv.roles.map(r => `${r}`).join(' | '),true)
    .setColor(0xffd000)
    .setFooter('Server Roles.')
    .setFooter(`Requested by @${author.tag}`,`${author.avatarURL}`)

message.channel.sendEmbed(myInfo);
```

**My main goal here is to tag the user in the embed message without tagging the user.**
My main focus is to get https://i.stack.imgur.com/ippZZ.jpg to https://i.stack.imgur.com/A0VnK.jpg but the ping does NOT actually ping anyone located in the embed.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

These text-based properties of [RichEmbed](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v11/class/RichEmbed)s (v11) and [MessageEmbed](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageEmbed)s (v12) do **not** support mentions...

- Author
- Title
- Field Name
- Footer

These don't even support any markdown...

- Author
- Footer

Because a footer can't parse the mention, it shows up as the string you see. Also, a user will not be given a notification for their mention in any part of an embed. Finally, the [`TextChannel#sendEmbed()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v11/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=sendEmbed) method is deprecated and has been removed in v12 of Discord.js; use [`TextChannel#send()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=send).

This code will use the author's tag instead of trying to parse a mention in the footer. **If you want to use the user's mention without pinging them, you can place it in any part of the embed not listed above.** Otherwise, their mention must be part of the message content.

```js
var myInfo = new discord.RichEmbed() // v11 only
  .setColor(...)
  .setAuthor(...)
  .addField(...)
  .setFooter(`Requested by ${message.author.tag}.`, message.author.displayAvatarURL);

message.channel.send(myInfo)
  .catch(console.error);
```

Comment: My issue was that in the embed, the mention wasn't tagging the user without the actual ping. It looks like https://imgur.com/a/hbgm1TX

Comment: @SomePerson "Because a footer can't translate the mention, it shows up as the string you see. Also, a user will **not** be given a notification for their mention inside of an embed." There's no way to get a mention in the properties of an embed listed in this answer, and there's no way for any mention inside of an embed to ping a user. These are restrictions within the Discord API.