# Why is my mention not working in discordpy?

Tags: python, discord.py

@*"my username"* don't work to show up inside an embed.

[image]

```python
@client.command()
async def user(ctx, subcommand, name):
    player = osu.fetch_user(username=name)
    if subcommand == "stats":
        embed = discord.Embed(title=f"osu! stats of {name}")
        id = 416651818760929291
        embed.set_footer(text=f"Shuka (osu! bot) by <@{id}>", icon_url="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/92/f7/cb/92f7cbba6e1f629f619ad878066ededc.png")
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't mention a user in the footer of an embed, hence the display you get. There is no problem in retrieving the user name that you do. (And all markdown is also disabled in the footer)

Answer (score 1):

As I stated in the comments - the **embed footer doesn't support mentions** (the same is with embed title, author and field name). Therefore best solution, in this case, is to get only your name:

```py
user = await client.fetch_user(416651818760929291)
embed.set_footer(text=f"Shuka (osu! bot) by {user}")
```

---

**or use mention where it's supported (ex. description):**

`<@!{id}>` instead of `<@{id}>` - you forgot to use `!` after `@`:

```py
embed.description = f"Shuka (osu! bot) by <@!{id}>"
```

or you can also **[fetch_user](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?%20user#discord.Client.fetch_user)** and then use `mention`:

```py
user = await client.fetch_user(416651818760929291)
embed.description = f"Shuka (osu! bot) by {user.mention}"
```

Comment: It's still not working ( https://codeshare.io/YLyVAE )

Comment: Oh. Sorry, I forgot that you wanted to use it in `embed footer` which unfortunately doesn't support mentions in the `embed footer`. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57112737/14048071) to learn which embed fields mentioning isn't allowed in.

Comment: And because of that, I would suggest using the user without `.mention`. Change `{user.mention}` to just `{user}`. You wouldn't get the mention, but at least your username will appear with the tag.  Another option you have is to move this to embed description which supports mentions.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the [`User`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Client.get_user), then use the `mention` attribute

```
#somewhere in your globals
bot.creator = client.get_user(416651818760929291)

...

@client.command()
async def user(ctx, subcommand, name):
    player = osu.fetch_user(username=name)
    if subcommand == "stats":
        embed = discord.Embed(title=f"osu! stats of {name}")
        embed.set_footer(text=f"Shuka (osu! bot) by {self.bot.creator.mention}>", icon_url="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/92/f7/cb/92f7cbba6e1f629f619ad878066ededc.png")
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Comment: I get an error message:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "h:\py\Projects\osuBot\main.py", line 7, in <module>
    bot.creator = bot.get_user(416651818760929291)
AttributeError: module 'discord.ext.commands.bot' has no attribute 'get_user'

Comment: My mistake, I edited. It's supposed to be `client.get_user`